# XMPP Jabber Hosting

Tags: xmpp

Looks like my shared hosting plan does not cover running a Jabber server. Does anyone know of any free or very cheap solutions for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Apps for Domains](http://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain/new) provides XMPP support.
Dreamhost will host a Jabber server for you on their cheap web hosting plans. Although I had a bit of a falling-out with Dreamhost over a policy of theirs that penalized me for registering a domain that I later wanted to transfer to a friend of mine who was also hosted on Dreamhost.